# How to add "Column Search" with infyom laravel-generator datatable

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable, infyom

Is-it possible to add "Column Search" with infyom laravel-generator yajra datatable.

I change tables_searchable_default from false to true

form this doc https://www.infyom.com/open-source/laravelgenerator/docs/8.0/configuration#options

But It does not change anything ...

Does so has a solution?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Post your yajra datatables code

Comment: Hi @sta don't know which file(s) you want, I use this cde "php artisan infyom:scaffold $Model --fromTable --tableName=$table --datatables=true" and infyom creates all the conf in many differents files ...

Answer (score 0):

My answer on Infyom Gihthub

https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues/972

How I did it (with a little modification in yajra/datables-html/builler - see Step 5)

```
0-https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
◦ reference example
1-php artisan infyom.publish:templates
2-resources/infyom/infyom-generator-templates/scaffold/views/datatable_body.stub
```

datatable_body.stub
@section('third_party_stylesheets')
@include('layouts.datatables_css')
@endsection

{{-- $dataTable->table(['width' => '100%', 'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered']) --}}
{!! $dataTable->table(['width' => '100%', 'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],true) !!}  {{-- drawFooter --}}

```
3 config/datatables-html.php
```

'datatables::script',
    'script' => 'layouts/script',
];

    4 resources/views/layouts/script.blade.php

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $("#dataTableBuilder tfoot th").each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( "" );
    } );
});

$(function(){window.{{ config('datatables-html.namespace', 'LaravelDataTables') }}=window.{{ config('datatables-html.namespace', 'LaravelDataTables') }}||{};window.{{ config('datatables-html.namespace', 'LaravelDataTables') }}["%1$s"]=$("#%1$s").DataTable(%2$s
        ,initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;    
                $( "input", this.footer() ).on( "keyup change clear", function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    } ); }
);

    5 • vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-html/src/Html/Builder.php

    public function generateScripts()
    {
        $parameters = $this->generateJson();
$parameters=substr($parameters,0,strlen($parameters)-1);    # remove the last } in order to add a parameter
        return new HtmlString(
            sprintf($this->template(), $this->getTableAttribute('id'), $parameters)
        );
    }